# how to fully cover one div on another

Tags: html, css

i going to create a progress bar, just like the picture below(ues red and green for sharp contrast).
[progress bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvtTi.png)

my codes is as follows

```
// react 
class App extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div className='home-page-wrapper'>
        <ProgressBar />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// css 
.outter {
  width: 260px;
  height: 46px;
  border-radius: 22px;
  background: green;
  overflow: hidden;
  

  .inner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    transform: translateX(100px);
  }
}
```

the problem is that the red div can not full cover the green one, it looks like that the red div has a green border, how can i do?

Comment: Please create a minimal demo to reproduce the issue... Anyway it works as expected https://jsfiddle.net/ym3qhp2g/2/

Answer (score 0):

You may use this code:

```css
.outter {
    width: 260px;
    height: 46px;
    border-radius: 22px;
    background: green;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.outter .inner {
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    border-radius: 22px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outter">
  <div class="inner" style="width: 70%;"></div>
</div>
```

change the `.inner` width property to perform the progression.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```css
.progress-bar {
  width:90%;
  height:30px;
  overflow:hidden;
  background:green;
  border-radius:6px;
}

.bar {
  float:left;
  height:100%;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar">
    <div class="bar" style="width:45%">
    </div>
</div>
```